# Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50c03) with this library (version 0x50c00)

Tags: linux, docker, qt, alpine-linux

I use alpine-php fpm  docker container for developing and deploying a php application. I want to use `wkhtmltopdf` for generating pdfs. I installed by using `apk add wkhtmltopdf` But when I run it I receive `Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50c03) with this library (version 0x50c00)` Since I needed to install quite a lot of packages for this app I'm not sure which package from the list bellow installs qt as a dependacy:

```
 apk add --no-cache \
            mysql-client \
            php7-mysqli \
            php7-pdo \
            freetype \
            libpng \
            freetype-dev \
            libpng-dev \
            jpeg-dev \
            libjpeg \
            libjpeg-turbo-dev \
            wget \
            zlib-dev \
            ttf-freefont \
            fontconfig \
            xvfb \
            libxrender-dev \
            gettext \
            gettext-dev \
            libxml2-dev \
            gnu-libiconv-dev \
            autoconf \
            g++ \
            git \
            bash \
            ca-certificates \
            make
```

Is there any way to figure out what of these packages installed qt and how can I fix the compatibility issue?

Comment: For your apk command, 103 packages are installed, but it seems none of them is qt, plus, qt is not on the `yavin/alpine-php-fpm` image to begin with. I suspect this issue is related to `wkhtmltopdf` itself - it/its qt dependency may be broken.

Comment: This guy has manually built a `wkhtmltopdf` Alpine container with patched qt, which suggests there's indeed an issue with qt:
https://github.com/madnight/docker-alpine-wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: Generally speaking, you could use `apk info -a <libname>` to the dependencies of each package. See https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management for more details.